# What is the aftermath of canceling a Google Apps / Google for Work subscription

Tags: google-apps-for-work

What happens to myname@mycompany.com google account after our Google for Work subscription is cancelled? Can I somehow preserve some aspect of it for future use, or can I recreate a new personal google account with that email id? I am also interested in knowing what other fallout will occur with a switch away from Google for Work, considering that my company has been using it for 6 years since it's inception.

Clarifications:

My company is likely going to migrate from Google for Work to Office 365 for email + productivity suite (don't ask me why, ugh), and we have several users who have come to rely on their Google for Work accounts to login to other sites and services, and I want to know what is going to happen if we cancel our Google for Work subscription for those users. For example, when I login to Trello, Stack Exchange, Bitbucket and many many more services, I don't put in a password, I use the "login with google" option and a lot of services are linked to my google account.

I am also very interested in knowing any other pain points regarding switches away from google.

Comment: By one side the question is too broad, by the other side adding "also interest in..." thing should be included in the question, not in a comment but that will make the question even broader.

Comment: Agreed that my question sucked :)

Answer (score 3):

## Short partial answer

Don't cancel the subscription, just change the MX records.

## Long partial answer

If you cancel the subscription your users could not use their Google Apps for Work accounts to sign in to third party services. If this is something that will happen the, then your users should update their accounts to use another method to sign in.

By the other hand, you could have Google Apps for Work and Office 365 or almost any other service using the same domain, even the email service could be used on both but you should carefully plan your company email routing.

## References

... and detailed information

- [Google Apps Administrator Help](http://support.google.com/a/)